# Insert into mysql table, but why json_encode return null?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Why does my application inputs values ​​in the database correctly, but the value returned by json to my android application is NULL?

The problem is in the web, but this works fine from the browser.

The function json_last_error () returns 0.

My php code:

```
<?php

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$passw = $_POST['password'];
$cpassw = $_POST['cpassword'];

$res = 0;

require_once 'funciones_bd.php';
$db = new funciones_BD();

if($db->isuserexist($usuario,$passw)){
    // echo(" Este usuario ya existe ingrese otro diferente!");
    $res = 1;       
}else{
    if($db->adduser($usuario,$passw)) { 
        // echo(" El usuario fue agregado a la Base de Datos correctamente.");          
        $res = 2;               
    }else{
        // echo(" ha ocurrido un error.");
        $res = 3;

    }

}
if ($res==2) {
    $resultado[]=array("logstatus"=>"1");
}
else {
    $resultado[]=array("logstatus"=>"0");
}
echo json_encode($resultado);
echo json_last_error();
?>
```

My Logcat:

```
10-03 18:59:43.991: I/Choreographer(5426): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-03 18:59:50.261: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(5426): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
10-03 18:59:50.261: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(5426):   in android.widget.EditText{4110cd60 VFED..CL .F....I. 15,497-465,546 #7f050004 app:id/edpassword}
10-03 18:59:50.261: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(5426):   0: sent at 27274938000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=27274938, downTime=27274788, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
10-03 18:59:53.090: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(5426): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
10-03 18:59:53.090: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(5426):   in android.widget.EditText{4110f430 VFED..CL .F....ID 15,575-465,624 #7f050007 app:id/reppassword}
10-03 18:59:53.090: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(5426):   0: sent at 27277780000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=27277780, downTime=27277671, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
10-03 18:59:57.960: D/dalvikvm(5426): GC_CONCURRENT freed 502K, 9% free 6389K/7016K, paused 136ms+182ms, total 661ms
10-03 18:59:58.300: E/getpostresponse(5426):  result= <br />
10-03 18:59:58.300: E/getpostresponse(5426): <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
10-03 18:59:58.300: E/getpostresponse(5426): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: cpassword in C:\wamp\www\android\adduser.php on line <i>5</i></th></tr>
10-03 18:59:58.300: E/getpostresponse(5426): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
10-03 18:59:58.300: E/getpostresponse(5426): <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
10-03 18:59:58.300: E/getpostresponse(5426): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0000</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>142712</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\android\adduser.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\adduser.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
10-03 18:59:58.300: E/getpostresponse(5426): </table></font>
10-03 18:59:58.300: E/getpostresponse(5426): [{"logstatus":"1"}]0
10-03 18:59:58.300: E/log_tag(5426): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
10-03 18:59:58.300: D/JSON(5426): null
10-03 18:59:59.264: E/JSON(5426): ERROR
10-03 18:59:59.300: E/onPostExecute=(5426): err
10-03 18:59:59.580: I/Choreographer(5426): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-03 19:00:07.201: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(5426): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app is receiving an XDebug error message and this value:

```
[{"logstatus":"1"}]0
```

This is *not* valid JSON because there is a `0` on the end of it. So your app cannot parse this as a JSON array.

Firstly, you need to fix that PHP problem. Apparently `cpassword` is not in the POST request. Maybe you need to add this, or maybe you need to check if it present before trying to use it.

Then, try commenting out this line of your PHP:

```
echo json_last_error();
```

Then your app should be able to parse the response as JSON properly.

Comment: Adding as a comment

    // $ cpassw = $ _POST ['cPassword'];

And everything works fine.

So the validation of the password on the android app is done in java. But, how do the validation in the web application?

Comment: Your PHP error is that `cpassword` is not in the `$_POST` array.  If you need it to be in there, you should check that your Android app is adding this value and that it's key is actually cpassword.